# With PayPal JS SDK, how to conditionally 'run' the onApprove part?

Tags: paypal

I have implemented a sandbox environment with PayPal JS SDK and the corresponding PHP SDK.

In JavaScript I use:

```
paypal.Buttons({
  createOrder: function(data, actions) {
    return fetch('../checkout-sdk/samples/CaptureIntentExamples/CreateOrder.php', {
      method: 'post',
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json'
      }
    }).then(function(resp) {
      respjs = resp.json();
      return respjs;
    }).then(function(orderData) {
      order_id = orderData.id;
      return order_id;
    });
  },

  onApprove: function(data, actions) {
    return fetch('../checkout-sdk/samples/CaptureIntentExamples/CaptureOrder.php?order_id='+data.orderID, {
      method: 'post',
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        orderID: data.orderID
      })
    }).then(function(appr_res) {
      apprjs = appr_res.json();
      return apprjs;
    }).then(function(orderData) {
      var errorDetail = Array.isArray(orderData.details) && orderData.details[0];

      if (errorDetail) {
        if (errorDetail.issue === 'INSTRUMENT_DECLINED') {
          return actions.restart(); // Recoverable state, per:
          // https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/funding-failure/
        } else {
          var msg = 'Sorry, your transaction could not be processed.';
          if (errorDetail.description) msg += '\n\n' + errorDetail.description;
          if (orderData.debug_id) msg += ' (' + orderData.debug_id + ')';
          return alert(msg); // Show a failure message
        }
      }

      // Successful capture! For demo purposes:
      console.log('Capture result', JSON.stringify(orderData, null, 2));
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.error("There was a problem with the approval fetch: ", error);
    });
  },
  onError: function(err) {
  alert(err);
  }
}).render('#paypal-button-container');
```

When the function createOrder fails, the PHP-script CreateOrder.php should return a message to the javascript SDK so it's possible to inform the customer.

On failing, the onApprove does not needed to 'run'.
How can I change the code to conditionally let 'run' the onApprove function?

I tried something like below on JSLint:

```
paypal.Buttons({
  createOrder: function(data, actions) {
    return fetch(url, {
      method: "post"
    }).then(function(res) {
      return res.json();
    }).then(function(orderData) {
      return orderData.id;
    });
  },

  if (orderData !== false) { // error: Expected ')' and instead saw '!=='.
    onApprove: function(data, actions) {
      return fetch(url2 + data.orderID, {
        method: "post"
      }).then(function(res) {
        return res.json();
      }).then(function(orderData) {
        //
      });
    },
  }
}).render("#paypal-button-container");
```

but JSLint reported: Expected ')' and instead saw '!=='.

How can I conditionally implement an if-then condition there?

Answer (score 0):

onApprove is already conditional on the create being successful and the order being successfully approved by the customer. It will not be called otherwise. You do not need to do anything.

Comment: Oh, that's good news. Thank you for your explanation.